# Listen to twiml without calling number

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am making my TwiML for incoming calls and want to hear what it sounds like without having to call the phone number directly. Are there any twilio dev tools that help with that problem?

I tried looking through the developer console and searching online, but I couldn't find anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">I want to hear this message without calling my number!</Say>
</Response>
```

I expect to hit a listen button and hear Alices voice say the message that I've written, but in order to do that I have to call my twilio number, and I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Haroun Ansari - I think you have an answer from @Alan which will solve your problem. If you select language English (Canada) (en-CA) then you can select Alice as voice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this from the Twilio console, visit the link below, when logged into your Twilio console:

[Text-to-Speech](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/text-to-speech)

Then select the language under Current Language Mapping, say "English (US) (en-US)" and then under "Test this Voice", enter the phrase and click the play button to listen to it.

Comment: Is it possible to do this via code programmatically rather than having to use the Twilio console?